# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null ... 'line284'

Tags: javascript

I am receiving an error message of `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"` when JavaScript tries to read:

```
getProper.style.border = "1px solid black";
```

(listed in my validate function and designated by ---> <--- )

I'm not sure why the error is happening. It's certainly not a spelling issue, so can anybody help me determine what it is and how to fix it? I have posted my entire code if that helps.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    function $(x) {
        var theElement = document.getElementById(x);
        return theElement;
    }

    function makeTimes(){
        var formTag = document.getElementsByTagName("form"), 
            selectLi = $('select'),
            makeSelect = document.createElement('select');
            makeSelect.setAttribute("id", "times");   
        for (var i=0, j=contactTimes.length; i<j; i++){
            var makeOption = document.createElement('option');
            var optText = contactTimes[i];
            makeOption.setAttribute("value", optText);
            makeOption.innerHTML = optText;
            makeSelect.appendChild(makeOption);
        }
        selectLi.appendChild(makeSelect);
    }

    function getCheckboxValue(){
        var checkboxes = document.forms[0].appointmentType;
            checkedValues = [];                             
        for (var i=0, j=checkboxes.length; i<j; i++){       
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {                   
                var checkedValue = checkboxes[i].value;     
            checkedValues.push(checkedValue);           
            }
        }
    }

    function getSelectedRadio(){
        var radios = document.forms[0].proper;
        for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++){
            if(radios[i].checked) {
                properValue = radios[i].value;
            }
        }
    }

    function setMessage(pclass, text){
        var newNode = document.createElement("p");
        newNode.setAttribute("class", pclass);
        newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        var messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');
        messageDiv.appendChild(newNode);
    }

    function toggleControls(n){
        switch(n){
            case "on":
                $('appointmentForm').style.display = "none";
                $('clearData').style.display = "inline";
                $('displayData').style.display = "none";
                $('addNew').style.display = "inline";
                break;
            case "off":
                $('appointmentForm').style.display = "block";
                $('clearData').style.display = "inline";
                $('displayData').style.display = "inline";
                $('addNew').style.display = "none";
                $('items').style.display = "none";
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    function storeData(key){
        if(!key){
            var id                  = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000001);
        }else{
            id = key;
        }
    getCheckboxValue();
    getSelectedRadio();
    var item                    = {};
        item.appointmentType    = ["Appointment Type:", checkedValues];
        item.fName              = ["First Name:", $('fName').value];
        item.lName              = ["Last Name:", $('lName').value];
        item.address1           = ["Address 1:", $('address1').value];
        item.address2           = ["Address 2:", $('address2').value];
        item.city               = ["City:", $('city').value];
        item.zipCode            = ["Zip Code:", $('zipCode').value];
        item.tele               = ["Telephone:", $('tele').value];
        item.email              = ["Email:", $('email').value];
        item.proper             = ["Own/Rent:", properValue];
        item.times              = ["Time:", $('times').value];
        item.yourDate           = ["Scheduled For:", $('yourDate').value];
        item.SRC                = ["Special Requests:", $('src').value];
        item.range              = ["Urgency Level:", $('uOfA').value];

    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(item));
    alert("message here.");
    }

    function getData(){
        toggleControls("on");
        if(localStorage.length === 0){
            alert("message here.");
        }
        //This writes the data from the local storage to the browser.
        var makeDiv = document.createElement('div');           
        makeDiv.setAttribute("id", "items");                   
        var makeList = document.createElement('ul');           
        makeDiv.appendChild(makeList);                         
        document.body.appendChild(makeDiv);                    
        $('items').style.display = "block";                    
        for (var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++){
            var makeli = document.createElement('li');
            var linksLi = document.createElement('li');
            makeList.appendChild(makeli);
            var key = localStorage.key(i);
            var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
            var obj = JSON.parse(value);
            var makeSubList = document.createElement('ul');     
            makeli.appendChild(makeSubList);
            for(var n in obj){
               var makeSubli = document.createElement('li');
               makeSubList.appendChild(makeSubli);
               var optSubText = obj[n][0]+" "+obj[n][1];
               makeSubli.innerHTML = optSubText;
               makeSubList.appendChild(linksLi);
            }
            makeItemLinks(); 
        }
    }

    function makeItemLinks(key, linksLi){
        var editLink  = document.createElement('a');
        editLink.href = "#";
        editLink.key  = key;
        var editText  = "Edit Appointment";
        editLink.addEventListener("click", editItem);
        editLink.innerHTML = editText;
        linksLi.appendChild(breakTag);

        var breakTag = document.createElement('br');
        linksLi.appendChild(breakTag);

        var deleteLink  = document.createElement('a');
        deleteLink.href = "#";
        deleteLink.key  = key;
        var deleteText  = "Delete Appointment";
        //deleteLink.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
        deleteLink.innerHTML = deleteText;
        linksLi.appendChild(deleteLink);
    }

    function editItem(){
        var value = localStorage.getItem(this.key);
        var item  = JSON.parse(value);

        toggleControls("off");

        var checkboxes = document.forms[0].appointmentType;
        for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].value == "getAFreeEstimate" && item.appointmentType[1] == "getAFreeEstimate"){
                checkboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }else if(checkboxes[i].value == "lawnService" && item.appointmentType[1] == "lawnService"){
                checkboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }else if(checkboxes[i].value == "sprinklerSystemService" && item.appointmentType[1] == "sprinklerSystemService"){
                checkboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }else if(checkboxes[i].value == "flowerBedMaintenance" && item.appointmentType[1] == "flowerBedMaintenance"){
                checkboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }else if(checkboxes[i].value == "hedgeTreeService" && item.appointmentType[1] == "hedgeTreeService"){
                checkboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }else if(checkboxes[i].value == "handymanServices" && item.appointmentType[1] == "handymanServices"){
                checkboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }else if(checkboxes[i].value == "other" && item.appointmentType[1] == "other"){
                checkboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }
        }       
        $('fName').value            = item.fName[1];
        $('lName').value            = item.lName[1];
        $('address1').value         = item.address1[1];
        $('address2').value         = item.address2[1];
        $('city').value             = item.city[1];
        $('zipCode').value          = item.zipCode[1];
        $('tele').value             = item.tele[1];
        $('email').value            = item.email [1];
        var radios = document.forms[0].proper;
        for(var i=0, i<radios.length; i++){
            if(radios[i].value == "Own" && item.proper[1] == "Own"){
                radios[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }else if(radios[i].value == "Rent" && item.proper[1] == "Rent"){
                radios[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }
        $('times').value            = item.times[1];
        $('yourDate').value         = item.yourDate[1];
        $('SRC').value              = item.SRC[1];
        $('range').value            = item.range[1];

        saveData.removeEventListener("click", storeData);
        $('submit').value = "Edit Appointment";
        var editSubmit = $('submit');
        editSubmit.addEventListener("click", validate);
        editSubmit.key = this.key;
        }

  }

    function deleteItem(){
        var ask = confirm("message here.");
        if(ask){
            localStorage.removeItem(this.key);
            alert("message here.");
            window.location.reload();
        }else{
            alert("message here.");
        }
    }

    function clearLocal(){
        if(localStorage.length === 0){
            alert("message here.");
        }else{
            localStorage.clear();
            alert("message here.");
            window.location.reload();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validate(ed){  
        var getTimes    = $('times');
        var getFname    = $('fName');
        var getLname    = $('lName');
        var getAddress1 = $('address1');
        var getCity     = $('city');
        var getZipCode  = $('zipCode');
        var getTele     = $('tele');
        var getEmail    = $('email');
        var getProper   = $('proper');
        var getYourDate = $('yourDate');

        errMsg.innerHTML = "";
        getTimes.style.border    = "1px solid black";
    getFname.style.border    = "1px solid black";
    getLname.style.border    = "1px solid black";
    getAddress1.style.border = "1px solid black";
    getCity.style.border     = "1px solid black";
    getZipCode.style.border  = "1px solid black";
    getTele.style.border     = "1px solid black";
    getEmail.style.border    = "1px solid black";
  --->  getProper.style.border   = "1px solid black";  <---

    getYourDate.style.border = "1px solid black";


        var messageAry = [];
        if(getTimes.value === "<-- select -->"){
            var timesError = "message here.";
            getTimes.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(timesError);
        }

        if (getFname.value === ""){
            var fNameError = "message here.";
            getFname.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(fNameError);
        }

        if (getLname.value === ""){
            var lNameError = "message here.";
            getLname.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(lNameError);
        }

        if (getAddress1.value === ""){
            var address1Error = "message here.";
            getAddress1.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(address1Error);
        }

        if (getCity.value === ""){
            var cityError = "message here.";
            getCity.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(cityError);
        }

        var re = /^\d{5}$/;
        if (!(re.exec(getZipCode))){
            var zipCode = "message here.";
            getZipCode.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(zipCodeError);
        }

        var re = /^[0-9\-\(\)\s]*$/.test(x) && x.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'').length == 10;
        if (!(re.exec(getTele))){
            var teleError = "message here.";
            getTele.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(teleError);
        }

        var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (!(re.exec(getEmail))){
            var emailError = "message here.";
            getEmail.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(emailError);
        }

        if (getProper.value === ""){
            var proper = "message here.";
            getProper.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(properError);
        }

        if(getYourDate.value === ""){
            var yourDate = "message here.";
            getYourDate.style.border = "1px solid red";
            messageAry.push(yourDateError);
        }

        if(messageAry.length >= 1){
            for(var i=0, j=messageAry.length; i<j; i++){
                var txt = document.createElement('li');
                txt.innerHTML = messageAry[i];
                errMsg.appendChild(txt);
            }
            ed.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }else{
            saveData(this.key);
        }   
    }

    //Variable defaults
    var contactTimes = ["<-- select -->", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening"],
        properValue,
        appointmentType,
        checkedValues,
        errMsg = $('errors')
    ;

    //Run makeTimes();
    makeTimes();

    var saveData = $('submit');
    saveData.addEventListener("click", validate);
    var clearData = $('clearData');
    clearData.addEventListener("click", clearLocal);
    var displayData = $('displayData');
    displayData.addEventListener("click", getData);

});
```

Comment: Can you at least narrow it down. This is too much code.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a lot of errors because your jQuery selectors are all wrong.

For example:
     var getProper   = $('proper');

There is no HTML element called 'proper'. So it should either be `var getProper   = $('.proper');` if it has a className 'proper' or `var getProper   = $('#proper');` when it has an id 'proper'.

Same goes for all your other selectors in the function.

Comment: First function in the posted code `function $(x) { ... }` -> no jQuery here